# JaxWS WSDL customization

Tags: weblogic, jax-ws

I'm using the **start-from-java** approach to develop a webservice , that will be published to WebLogic 10.3.6.
I'm using annotations to define a WS Beans , methods and Types.
I'm using a **JWSC** ant task to generate the deployable service and **clientgen** ant task to generate client artefacts.

The output is  (as expected) fine , but I have certain restrictions upon the generated WSDL file , which I can't find the solution for. I've tried to play around with **binding xml file** , but the changes are applied only to the generated client artefacts . 
The restrictions are :

1. the schema import has to define a targetNamespace="" element

although the targetNamespace element is specified is the xsd schema file

1. The message part

has to have  the naming convention of `*Request` 
Annotating the parameter with `@WebParam(name="someRequest")` didn't change the message part in the wsdl , but instead in the xsd  schema file .

Comment: The schema snippet  : 
<xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://stas.asd.com" schemaLocation="CopyOfCopyOfWithInterfaceService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>

Comment: The message part snippet :
      <input message="tns:get"/>
      <output message="tns:getResponse"/>